# When set iPhone language to Chinese or Japanese,the WatchKit Extension's connected outlet is nil at runtime

Tags: swift, watchkit

I want to localize watch app's content,however, currently it is impossible to set languages in watch app. So I guess watch app's language is tied to iPhone(After trial,I think it really is),when I set iPhone's language to Chinense(Simplified) or Japanese,the outlet in WatchKit Extension is nil with surprise(for example, MKInterfaceLabel),is it a bug in XCode6.2 beta3 or something else should be configured?
Here is the snippet code relevant to this issue.

in WatchKit Extension:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
        let title = NSLocalizedString("title", comment: "localized Title")
        println(title)
        mLabel.setText(title)
    }

}
```

And I have set iPhone's Language to Japanese
[image]

However,when I run it in WatchApp Scheme,watch app crashed,because label outlet is nil.

[image]

Comment: What is the specific error message on the crash?

Comment: The outlet label is nil

Comment: What result do you see from `println(title)`? Most likely, 'title' is nil and thus mLabel.setText(title) is failing to set the *label*, which is what your error message say, rather than that the *outlet* itself is nil which is what you were thinking. It appears in WatchKit that some labels are required, that would be optional in iOS.

Comment: The result is that the mLabel instance is nil when debugging.(XCode6.2 beta3).

Comment: Yes, your screenshot shows that mLabel is nil. But what is printed in the log from `println(title)`?

Comment: The printed message is correct according to the Localized.String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the Watch uses the language setting for the iPhone. (Or at least, the Watch Extension does, we don't have insight into the Watch more generally at present.)

Have you connected your IBOutlet mLabel in your WatchKit Extension up to the corresponding label in the Watch App in interface builder?